# How does virtualbox NAT works

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, nat

When I select NAT in network settings, my guest vm gets 10.0.2.15 with gateway 10.0.2.2. But I don't see any virtual devices on my host. What does actually perform NAT functions?

As I imagine it to be: there are virtual device with one ip on my host machine and another on NAT network. There are 10.0.2.2 for NAT network. But where is it's ip on my host machine?

Comment: [VirtualBox network documentation on NAT](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat_service) your host network adapter is used.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, NAT is performed internally by VirtualBox itself. The VM isn't directly attached to your host kernel's networking at all – it goes through VirtualBox's own networking functions first, which acts as a NAT-capable router (or actually more like a [SLiRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slirp)-like gateway).